# neutron elastic collision energy distribution

Tags: statistics, physics

I'm interested in nuclear physics and want to accurately model nuclear reactions involving neutrons. I need to be able to calculate the the probability of each possible energy after an elastic collision with a particle of known weight. For example, if a neutron with a kinetic energy of $1$MeV hits a nucleus that weighs $100$ times as much as a neutron the neutron will end up with between $\approx0.961$MeV and $1$MeV depending on how direct the collision is. The wikipedia page for neutron moderator says that the energy lost per collision is on average $\approx\frac{2}{A+1}$ where $A$ is the mass ratio. I've noticed that using the neutron moderator equation on wikipedia gives an average energy loss of ~half the maximum possible so I assume the distribution is energy distribution symmetric.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the the probability of each possible energy?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have an equation for the approximate probability of each possible energy.

Answer (score 1):

No, the distribution is not symmetric in any sense.

First-principle calculation of the energy loss per collision depends on calculating the probabilities of various modes of excitation of the nucleus.  HEP codes such as Geant 3 and Geant 4 have functions for this built in; the data comes from years of experimental measurements.

You say you are interested in the situation for nuclei which are about 100 times the neutron mass. A further complication arises if you want scattering cross-sections for nuclei about twice that heavy, namely, that the data for those elements is classified.

Comment: Thanks I will look into using geant. Do the excitation modes change the likelihood of glancing bounces or do they change the energy distribution some other way? If the energy distribution is well approximated by assuming the nucleus to be spherical for high energy neutrons that would be good enough for the application I have in mind.